# Required input field

Tags: php, jquery

I have some input fields that are displayed from a loop using foreach. After click i want all of them to be required by using jquery. If the loop shows 1 or 3 inputs the required functions works perfectly but if the loop shows 2 inputs, only the first is required and the form can be saved with the second input empty. How can i solve this issue ?
Any help is really appreciated.

```
<form class="input-seg">
<?php

foreach($GET_INPUT as $get_input){
  ?>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label  class="control-label col-sm-3"><?=$get_input->name;?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input  type="text" name="inputname[]" class="form-control inp"   >
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.input-seg').click(function() {
  if($(".inp").val() == ""){
    $(".inp").focus();
    $('.inp').css('border', '2px solid'); 
    $('.inp').css('border-color', 'red');
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
      $('.inp').fadeTo('slow', 0.1).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    };
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: your for loop is repeating the same thing 3 times. You don't need this loop. It's not needed when you doing operations with classes.

Comment: Then how can i display the rows of input , so they are from a table. ?

Comment: This is another question. Please do a research before creating the question

Comment: `$(".inp")` is a collection of elements. So `$(".inp").val()` will get the value of the first input having the `inp` class... Not all. Same for `.focus()`... But `.css()` and `.fadeTo()` will have effet on the whole collection.

Comment: i did it, why do i have to seach ? it's because you wrote that i don't need it. The inputs fields are not repeated there are all different

Answer (score 1):

You should use [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) to validate your fields. The link shows a lot of examples. Handle $(this) inside your event listener is a much more elegant approach:

```
$('.inp').focusout(function() { validate your field element object $(this)  });
```